# vqmod not properly generating vqcache files v. 2.5.0

Tags: caching, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

Anyone found a way to get the vqmod cache files to generate properly?

I'm using VQmod manager 3.0 and that is what it's telling me.

Comment: VQMod works fine in OC 2 with VQMod 2.5.0+. Ensure your permissions are set correctly as per the docs

Comment: I did set permissions right but everything is fixed now thanks for the answer

Comment: could you tell me how you fixed this issue?